# Select list oracle apex second value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

When I create a Select list based on a SQL query it asks for 2 columns. For example I did something like: `select  itemcode, itemname  from items` in a select list called  LST_ITEMS. I need to retrieve or get both of the values when I call it with :LST_ITEMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query as:

```
select itemname display_value, 
       itemcode || ':' || itemname return_value
  from items
```

After that you will get combined value in `:LST_ITEMS` variable. You can parse it in PL/SQL code further. For example:

```
declare
   code number;
   name varchar2(100);
begin
   code = substr(:LST_ITEMS, 1, instr(:LST_ITEMS, ':') - 1);
   name = substr(:LST_ITEMS, instr(:LST_ITEMS, ':') + 1);
end;
```

Comment: Apex considers as display value the first item in your query and return value as the second, so your query should be like this `select itemname display_value, itemcode || ':' || itemname return_value
  from items `

Comment: @Cristian_I Thanks, I often forget about that.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Get That Using Javascript Dynamic Action Like so

```
$s('P1_Display_Val',apex.item("LST_ITEMS").displayValueFor("1"));
```

This copy the display value of item "LST_ITEMS" (with return value = 1) to item "P1_Display_Val". either 1 was the selected value or not.